# Creating new list with values from two prior lists

Tags: python, list

Given the lists  list1 and  list2 that are of the same length, create a new list consisting of the last element of  list1 followed by the last element of  list2 , followed by the second to last element of  list1 , followed by the second to last element of  list2 , and so on (in other words the new list should consist of alternating elements of the reverse of  list1 and  list2 ). For example, if  list1 contained  [1, 2, 3] and  list2 contained  [4, 5, 6] , then the new list should contain  [3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4] . Associate the new list with the variable  list3 .

My code:

```
def new(list1,list2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    new_list = []
    for j in list1:
        new_list[i-1] = list2[j-1]
        i+= 1
        j += 1
        new_list[i-1] = list2 [j-1]
        i+= 1
        j += 1
    return new_list
```

I know, it's messy =_=, help?

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework. If it is, you should tag it as such.

Comment: It's not only messy; it doesn't even work -- it will blow up the first time that you try to execute `new_list[i-1] = list2[j-1]`. Also `j` is a VALUE from list1 but you then use it as a SUBSCRIPT of list2! Suggestion: use test data values of 100, 200, etc -- if you attempt to use those as list subscripts, you'll get an exception immediately, not later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]

newl = []
for item1, item2 in zip(reversed(l1), reversed(l2)):
    newl.append(item1)
    newl.append(item2)

print newl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list(sum(zip(list1,list2)[::-1],()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way,

```
from itertools import izip
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
l = []
for _ in izip(reversed(l1), reversed(l2)): l.extend(_)
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest making your job much simpler by using the list `.append()` method instead?

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist.append(1)
>>> mylist
[1]
>>> mylist.append(7)
>>> mylist
[1, 7]
```

Also another small suggestion, instead of iterating over one list or the other, I'd suggest iterating over numerical indices:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
```

Comment: I don't want to go manually through both lists and add the values, I want to add from two pre-existing lists, thanks anyway.

Comment: But see, the `append()` method can take anything as it's argument... including an element of an existing list. Such as, say... `new_list.append(list1[i]))` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: list(x+y), reversed(zip(list1,list2)))
```

`list` is necessary as the prior operations return a tuple.

Comment: Golfed for fun: `sum(map(list,reversed(zip(list1,list2))),[])`

Comment: mm thanks for giving me the idea of passing `list()` to `reduce()`, instead of vice versa. Makes for less nesting.