# creating flat list from two lists

Tags: python

Given a list of values:

```
data = [100, 80, 200, 20, 300, 100, 400, 40, 500, 120, 600, 60]
```

I want to extract the first two and the last two values, and create a new list. Unfortunately, the way I'm doing things right now, I get a list which contains two lists:

```
bla = [data[0:2], data[-2:]]

print bla
 [[100, 80], [600, 60]]
```

Instead I would like to get this:

```
[100, 80, 600, 60]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?

(this question is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818763/creating-new-list-with-values-from-two-prior-lists), but I still think it's different enough)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use list concatenation with `+`:

```
data[0:2] + data[-2:]
```

Comment: The leading `0` is unecessary: `data[:2] + data[-2:]`

Answer (score 5):

Use `+` to concatenate the two sublists:

```
bla = data[:2] + data[-2:]

bla
[100, 80, 600, 60]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
bla = data[0:2] + data[-2:]
print bla
[100, 80, 600, 60]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to combine multiple iterables is to use `itertools.chain` to create an iterator:

```
import itertools
extractediter = itertools.chain(data[0:2], data[-2:])
```

The iterator won't itself create a new list, but will give you a structure that you can walk over just as you would a list:

```
for x in extractediter:
    print x
```

or compute the sum:

```
extractedtotal = sum(extractediter)
```

This can be an advantage if you are creating large lists or sublists, as the iterator won't make a copy, just a moving placeholder that you access each list item one at a time. The downside is that iterators are like generator expressions, in that you can only walk them once, and then they are said to be "consumed".

If you really just want another list, pass this to the `list` type constructor

```
extractedlist = list(extractediter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newdata = []
newdata.extend(data[:2])
newdata.extend(data[-2:])
```